# Is there any way to show records that are preventing a delete due to referencial integrity?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i have a generic problem all over my application and want to see if there is a common generic way of solving it.

The main issue is how to let users know which records are linked when you try to delete a record from a joined table.

for example, let's say i have two database tables.

1. Customer
2. Branch

where Customer has a branchId field.

if i go delete a record from the branch table, it will fail if there are customers that have that branchId in its foreign key.

if i try to delete this through code, i get an error saying that it can't delete because of a referencial integrity constraint but it doesn't let me know what the actual linked tables is or which particular records are causing the link.

Is there any generic C# code that handles this situation that would either:

1. Give a better error message back and show you the records that are links
2. Even better, lets you change the linked records at that time to a default reference or a null reference (in cases where the foreign key is nullable)

Comment: You should be proactif and warn that a customer cannot be deleted instead of being reactive to the exception.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant That's a nice concept -- however, in my world, the database is *the final gate-keeper* -- and sometimes you need the key(s). It seems like the goal here isn't to *display why* to the user, but to *determine why* for the developer.

Comment: With LINQ2SQL it will display the constraint that is violated (when connected to SQL Server 2008) -- perhaps there is something hiding the appropriate "full" SQL error message (or perhaps it's not reported by server X, which is sort of silly). As far as the latter questions, consider using the CASCADE support in the SQL database, if you intend the behavior. In either case, the complete set of relationships should be defined up-front and the messages used merely to aid in development if at all possible.

Comment: Isn't your database telling you which constraint is involved in the attempted referential integrity violation?  In the example you gave, you could name your constraint something like branch_customer_id_fk (table_key_fk where fk=foreign key), then when it complains it'll tell you which table and which key (or keys, if its compound.)

Comment: You can use a system view named `sys.foreign_key_columns` (SQL Server 2005 and higher, not sure about earlier versions) to obtain information about which columns of which *Customer*-like tables refer to which column of the *Branch*-like table. Using that info you can then find all the rows that will be affected, count them (to inform the user, or simply show them all), check the referrers for NULLability, modify them if possible (and if not, deny the operation), and lastly delete the record in question. So, a great deal of work, seems to me.

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant - what would be the best way to get all the records that will break due to this validation. it seems inefficient to do this on every delete query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating a trigger on the `Branch` table that sets any `Customer` records referencing the `Branch` record that is going to be deleted to BranchId = null.

This should allow you to delete Branches and remove any associations from existing customers.

[Here is an article](http://www.redware.com/handbooks/sql_server_handbook/sql_server_triggers.html) that goes over something similar.

Be warned that you will probably have some confused customers if you start changing their data without them knowing it...